# Ajax submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form1").submit(function (e){
        alert ('working 01');
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
        alert ('working 02');
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : '../portal.php',
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                $('#form1').fadeOut("slow");
                alert ('working 03');
                }

                })
  });
  return false;
});
```

I have echoed in several places to see where it goes wrong. only "working 02 is displayed and nothing happened. portal.php is ready to accept data. Here's my form.

```
 <form id="form1" method="post">
          <label class="label_title"> e-mail </label>
          <input type="text" id="email" required>

          <label class="label_title">Comments:</label>
          <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="com" id="com" class="textarea required" required ></textarea>
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send">
          </form>
```

Comment: Change button type to button, and call above function on click

Comment: open console and try the ajax function and check whether it shows any errors.
try this...
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : '../portal.php',
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                $('#form1').fadeOut("slow");
                alert ('working 03');
                }

                });

Answer (score 2):

you can't use submit and ajax, it's better to use click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function (e){
        alert ('working 01');
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
        alert ('working 02');
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : '../portal.php',
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                $('#form1').fadeOut("slow");
                alert ('working 03');
                }

                })
  });
});
```

P.S. it's better to remove the type="submit" from your button

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function (e){
        alert ('working 01');
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
        alert ('working 02');
         $.post('../portal.php',{data:$('#form1').serialize()},function(response){
             $('#form1').fadeOut("slow");
             alert ('working 03');
         });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanx, But results are same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="form1" method="post">
          <label class="label_title"> e-mail </label>
          <input type="text" id="email" required>

          <label class="label_title">Comments:</label>
          <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="com" id="com" class="textarea required" required ></textarea>
          <input type="button" class="button" id="submit" value="Send"><!--changed-->
          </form>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function (e){            //changed
        alert ('working 01');
          //  e.preventDefault();
           // var $form = $(this);
        alert ('working 02');
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : '../portal.php',
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                $('#form1').fadeOut("slow");
                alert ('working 03');
                }

                })
  });
  //return false;
});
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax is **asynchronus**.

so your `return false;`  called before the ajax request.

return on the success of ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form1").submit(function (e){
        alert ('working 01');
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
        alert ('working 02');
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : '../portal.php',
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                $('#form1').fadeOut("slow");
                alert ('working 03');
                return false;  
                }

                })
  });

});
```

Comment: earlier tried removing return false;. results same. thanks for supporting.

Comment: @TharakaandRukshan yes both behave sames

Comment: @TharakaandRukshan if you want to remove return statement then make sure you you are not using submit type of button